# Postgresql: How do I enable a high memory consumption query log similar to slow query log?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

Looking into approaches you would use to capture high memory consumption queries executed on a postgresql server(ie having some cap in mb that gets reported), similar to the way slow query logs can be configured.

Since I didn't ever come across any such configuration before, any custom implementations/solutions could give me some hint on the path I should take.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that.

Comment: There is an extension called [auto_explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html) Which logs individual queries with their actual plain. Maybe there is a way to extract actual costs (memory and disc usage is there already ) from its output.

Comment: That would be in interesting feature, but I don't think it could be implemented as an extension without some changes to the core.  I think that by the time that post-execution control passes to auto_explain, most of the memory would have already been freed without leaving any durable trace.